# Elastic Lucene query not working properly with date

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, elastic-stack

I have a simple task:

Get all the items from an elastic index with status 'paid' or 'done' for the last week.

What I tried is this:

```
GET /my_index/_search?q=((status:paid or status:done) and (created_at > "now-7d/d"))
```

The interesting part is, if I do

```
GET /my_index/_search?q=((status:paid or status:done)
```

I get around 4k results, but if I do the whole query, I get 600k. It appears, that if I add the 2nd part, something stops to work properly.

I have tested the query in the discover tab of Kibana and it is working properly there, but for some reason, it does not with the API. Any help will be appreciated.

PS: I cannot do the query in the body, as there are additional aggregate filters there, that I at least haven't found a way to combine with the above filters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track but you have three tiny syntax mistakes that make the query not work as intended.

- Change `(created_at > "now-7d/d")` to `(created_at :> "now-7d/d")`
- Change the `and` into `AND`, Currently `(x and y)` are being parsed into `x OR and OR y` which is why you're getting so many results.
- Change the `or` into `OR`, Same concept you're getting false matches due to it.

To summarize change your query into this:

`GET /my_index/_search?q=((status:paid OR status:done) AND (created_at :> "now-7d/d"))`